# Can I create a uri for some text in memory?

Tags: string, uri

There is a method `spawnUri(String uri)` which accepts a String uri parameter, it will locate the uri, and read the content from it.

I want to pass some text to it, that I can create a file and write the text to the file, then give the file uri to the function.

But I think is it possible to create a uri for the text directly, and give it to the string?

That is:

```
String text = "my text to pass to a function";
String uri = "???://???..." + text;   // how to do this !!!
spawnUri(uri);
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you want - but looks to me your solution would be a cgi script located at <http://localhost/cgi-bin/echo> that just echos it's content parameter on HTTP GET, so <http://localhost/cgi-bin/echo?content=this%20is%20my%20text> gives you "this is my text".

Comment: And the stuff above in angle brackets should in fact be a URL with some http: in front of it 8^(

Comment: Can you please show what the input and output is. I couldn't understand it exactly

Comment: Why do you want to read with spawnUri() a string that you already have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported yet. Here's a link to the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=5187).